Invert swipe direction in "Swipe between full-screen apps" trackpad gesture
In the Trackpad gestures available here, it shows Swipe between full-screen apps.
The description says: "Swipe left or right with four fingers2 to move between desktops and full-screen apps."

Is it possible to invert the direction?
The default setting is anti-natural to me.

Whether if it is with an external app (paid, free or open source), some code or whatever other solution.
Running Mac OS Sonoma 14.1

The tool I would go to first is BTT - https://folivora.ai/ they offer a 45 day free trial.

did you figure this out? I find it unnatural as well and can't seem to find a fix for it

Not solution for me at this point.

Just enable Natural Scrolling under System Settings > Trackpad > Scroll & Zoom


Hey, that did it!
Does it change anything else besides " Swipe between full-screen apps." ?
